# Google Script Calendar event end time overrun on all day events

Tags: calendar, google-apps-script

When I create an event and then access it via Google Script, I notice that the endTime overruns the actual day I set the event for. This can be very problematic when iterating over days in the calendar to get events.

Example:
Go into a Google Calendar and set an all day event with the standard defaults for todays date. Then execute the following code:

```
function foo() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var date = new Date();
  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(date);
  Logger.log("Events for today: "+date);
  for (var i=0; i<events.length;i++) {
      Logger.log(events[i].getTitle());
      Logger.log(" "+events[i].getStartTime());
      Logger.log(" "+events[i].getEndTime());
  }
  date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
  Logger.log("\nEvents for tomorrow: "+date);
  events = cal.getEventsForDay(date);
  for (var i=0; i<events.length;i++) {
      Logger.log(events[i].getTitle());
      Logger.log(" "+events[i].getStartTime());
      Logger.log(" "+events[i].getEndTime());
  }
}
```

Example output (from Google Script log):

```
Events for today: Wed Jul 04 2012 19:39:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Test
 Wed Jul 04 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
 Thu Jul 05 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

Events for tomorrow: Thu Jul 05 2012 19:39:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Test
 Wed Jul 04 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
 Thu Jul 05 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now revisited this issue 3 different times looking for solutions. The ONLY reasonable solution i can find is to create a new calendar at GMT+0. Then all "all day" events will align properly within a single day.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. There are many issues raised in the Issue tracker which you should subscribe to

1. [Issue 234](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=234)
2. [Issue 936](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=936)

Comment: Yeah, issue 936 is close to mine. I did play around with the time zone settings of my google account to see if this changed the behaviour of the "bug" but didn't see much change. I did not know however that there was a time zone setting for a calendar itself? Odd. I'll monitor that bug post for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same bug. My **All Day** events are coming out as starting 7pm EST the day before them. My temporary kluge is to check whether the All Day event starts today or not. Code snippet:

```
var allDayP = event.isAllDayEvent();
if (allDayP)
{
  titl = '<font color="red">' + event.getTitle() + '</font>';  
  if (Utilities.formatDate(event.getStartTime(), Session.getTimeZone(),"M/d") == Utilities.formatDate(now, Session.getTimeZone(),"M/d"))
  {
  startTime = "All Day Event The Next Day";
  endTime = Utilities.formatDate(event.getEndTime(), Session.getTimeZone(),"M/d")
  }
  else
  {
  startTime = "All Day Event Today";
  endTime = Utilities.formatDate(event.getEndTime(), Session.getTimeZone(),"M/d")
  }
}
```